# MySQL String Encoding Storage Space

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, ascii, latin1

I'm aware that `utf8` in MySQL is stored as a fixed length 3 bytes (24 bits)  and `utf4mb4` is a fixed 4 bytes. I presume Latin 1 to be a fixed length 1 byte - my question is is the mysql ascii type 7 bits and is there a slight storage savings over Latin-1?

Comment: "I'm aware that utf8 in MySQL is stored as a fixed length 3 bytes (24 bits)" at the risk of repeating from the answer, but just to be sure you understand: **no**, utf8 is **not** stored as fixed length 3 bytes. And I'm **not** speaking about char vs varchar here, the way characters are stored for instance in a text field will use one, two or three bytes according to the needs of that specific character.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I have since become aware.

Comment: Yeah, tbh I don't remember why I commented that. It's pretty clearly explained in the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial premise is incorrect.  In `VARCHAR` as well as `*TEXT` columns, utf8 and utf8mb4 characters only consume as many bytes of storage as are necessary for the utf8 representation of each character.  The only fixed multibyte allocation is for `CHAR` columns, since they are fixed width.

> Tip: To save space with UTF-8, use VARCHAR instead of CHAR. Otherwise, MySQL must reserve three bytes for each character in a CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8 column because that is the maximum possible length. For example, MySQL must reserve 30 bytes for a CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 column.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html

Otherwise, when storing utf8 and utf8mb characters, the maximum bytes per character is *not* used for each character:

> when using the utf8 (or utf8mb4) Unicode character set, you must keep in mind that not all characters use the same number of bytes and **can require up to** three (four) bytes per character. <sub>*[emphasis added]*</sub>
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

There is no 7 bit storage-byte-spanning character set.

However, compressing the entire table can be done in newer versions, and if you have sufficient CPU, the server can actually perform better with table compression enabled, if your disks are relatively slow or your server spends a lot of time being I/O-bound.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-compression.html

Comment: I've added an additional citation from the docs -- A utf8 character in MySQL is a *maximum* of 3 bytes, but a *minimum* of 1 byte.  You seem to be saying that utf8 characters in MySQL always occupy a "fixed length" of 3 bytes, as if there's a deliberate storage inefficiency in the interest of speed, but that's simply not the case.  A utf8 character in MySQL only occupies as many bytes in the row data as are required to store that character in its utf8 encoding (except in `CHAR` columns, where the maximum consumable space has to be allocated in the event all characters are of max width).